# Magento 1.9.1 Getting a 404 error page on multi store

Tags: multistore, ce-1.9.1.0, 404-page

My original magento store is on www.antistaticesd.com (default category)
My another store using the same magento and other root category(business store) is supposed to be at  www.antistaticesd.com/business

I changed the base URL in sysytem > Configuration to www.antistaticesd.com/business  for this store view.

I copied and pasted two files  index.php and  .htaccess from the root to the "business" directory.
When I hit www.antistaticesd.com/business  on the browser, it gives me a 404 error page.
Please tell me what further steps do I take to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this link to help me set up a Multi Store: https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase/30/How-to-Setup-Magento-with-Multiple-Stores-and-Domains.html Sounds like you're missing a few steps but the website link I've provided should help you through the whole process. I've manage to set up a separate store using another domain. Hope this helps!!!!